# connection.query is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js

I tried to use mySQL connection to do INSERT. But it says connection.query() is not a function. I can do INSERT in the sql.js file, but cannot in controller.js.

```
var connection=require('../../sql');
exports.render=function(req,res){
  res.render('login',{

  });
};
exports.create=function(req,res){
  res.render('signin');
};
exports.signin=function(req,res){
  var data  = {usr: 'goi', pwd: 'me'};
  connection.query('INSERT INTO login SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
    
  });
    res.render('layout');
};
```

**sql.js** (where I connected to MySQL)

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var connection=mysql.createConnection({
  host:'127.0.0.1',
  port: '3306',
  user:'root',
  password:'12345',
  database:'db'
});

connection.connect(function(error){
  if(!!error){
    console.log(error);
  }else{
    console.log('Connected!:)');
  }
});

module.exorts=connection;
```

Comment: Simple typo in `sql.js`; `module.exorts=connection;` should be `module.exports=connection;`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error within an 'async function'. In my case my call to the pool was not preceded by the the `await` keyword.

ERROR:

```js
let conn = pool.getConnection();
```

NO ERROR:

```js
let conn = await pool.getConnection();
```